# Regex Matching with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract parts of the following string:

```
#string-to-extract
#string-to-extract?foo1=fooA
#string-to-extract?foo1=fooA&foo2=fooB
```

I have the following regex:

```
var pattern = /#(.*)\?{0,1}/;
```

But the following line of code:

```
string.match(pattern);
```

Gives me the following results for the above string:

```
#string-to-extract     =>      [1]string-to-extract
#string-to-extract?foo1=fooA     =>      [1]string-to-extract?foo1=fooA
#string-to-extract?foo1=fooA&foo2=fooB     =>      [1]string-to-extract?foo1=fooA&foo2=fooB
```

When for all of them I want group 1 to always be `string-to-extract` only. What am I doing wrong with my regex?

Comment: `.match()` returns an array  `[1]string-to-extract` I'm assuming this is in the console which means that is an array of length 1, and you can get the string by referencing the index `[0]`

Comment: I would keep the regex simpler: `/#([\w-]+)/`

Comment: @maioman I suspect `string-to-extract` is just a placeholder and could be anything

Comment: @KillzoneKid `[\w-]` expands to `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` , if some char is missing you can add it;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` means "match everything you can and don't stop". In other words your `?` matches as part of group 1 before you specify you want to look for a question mark. Instead you want to match everything *except* a question mark. Like this:

```
/#([^?]+)\??/;
```

`[^?]` is a character class meaning "match anything that isn't this list of characters" (in your case a literal question mark). Instead of `*` I used `+` which mean 1 or more. And instead of `{0,1}` you can use just another `?` which means your literal `?` can exist or not exist

Comment: You don't have to escape question mark inside a character class.

Comment: ...and I assume `\??` is somehow redundant as `#([^?]+)` did what should have been done.

Comment: @revo yes, i tried it without the `\??` and it worked just fine. Thanks both for the help